# Problems with creating text files with ofstream in C++

Tags: c++, file-io, fstream, ifstream, ofstream

I am following a C++ textbook, currently at the part that is dealing with *ofstream* and *ifstream*. I have typed a couple of examples in the same *main()* function of a project ( CodeBlocks 13.12 ).

The problem is that some of the code at the beginning works fine, and the rest of it doesn't. I tried to explain it below, after the code.:

```
ofstream outfile("MyFile.dat");  

if (!outfile) 
{
cout << "Couldn’t open the file!" << endl;
}

outfile << "Hi" << endl;
outfile.close();

ofstream outfile2("MyFile.dat", ios_base::app); 
outfile2 << "Hi again" << endl; 
outfile2.close();


ifstream infile("MyFile.dat");
if (infile.fail())
{
cout << "Couldn't open the file!" << endl;
return 0;
}
infile.close();
ofstream outfile3("MyFile.dat", ios_base::app);
outfile3 << "Hey" << endl;
outfile3.close();


string word;
ifstream infile2("MyFile.dat");
infile2 >> word; 
cout << word << endl; // "Hi" gets printed, I suppose it only prints 1st line ?
infile2.close();


ifstream infile3("MyFile.dat");
if (!infile3.fail())
{
cout << endl << "The file already exists!" << endl;
return 0;
}
infile3.close();
ofstream outfile4("MyFile.dat");
outfile4 << "Hi Foo" << endl; 
outfile4.close();
// this piece of code erases everything in MyFile.dat - why ?


ofstream outfile5("outfile5.txt");
outfile5 << "Lookit me! I’m in a file!" << endl;
int x = 200;
outfile5 << x << endl;
outfile5.close();
```

When the code executes, the only created file is *MyFile.dat* and its contents are

```
Hi
Hi again
Hey
```

"Hi Foo" doesn't get written to the file and *"outfile5.txt"* is not created.

Can someone explain me **why part of the code doesn't work ?** And how to correct it, or what to keep an eye on for future reference ?

Comment: It would seem you have designed the code to exit early because it finds the existing file.

Comment: @RetiredNinja - Could you please point me to the instance where this happens ? I have copied the code from the textbook and it didn't mention any exiting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In

```
ifstream infile3("MyFile.dat");
if (!infile3.fail())
{
    cout << endl << "The file already exists!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

you exit (`return 0`) whenever testing for the successful opening of `"MyFile.dat"`.

In

```
ofstream outfile4("MyFile.dat");
outfile4 << "Hi Foo" << endl; 
outfile4.close();
// this piece of code erases everything in MyFile.dat - why ?
```

the content of "MyFile.dat" is being erased, since by default you open the stream for rewriting, and not appending. If you want to append, use

```
outfile.open("MyFile.txt", std::ios_base::app);
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, this clears the main issue. But if I am not asking too much, can you please look at the part of code that ends with a comment: "// this piece of code erases everything in MyFile.dat - why ?"  , and try expand your answer with explanation for this too ? Thank you.